# Route redirect with message variable

Tags: php, laravel

I need some help with Laravel. What I want to do is create a route filter that will redirect a user with a specified message passed from a variable. The code I currently have semi-works, the only that that I don't like though, is that the message gets converted to lowercase characters when displayed on the view.

```
Route::get('event/signup', array('before' => 'auth_message:You must be logged into your account to signup for the event.', 'uses' => 'event@signup'));

Route::filter('auth_message', function($message)
{
    if (!Auth::user())
    {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('errorAlert', $message);
    }
});
```

So for example, this message "You must be logged into your account to signup for the event." is displayed as this on the view after the user is redirected: "you must be logged into your account to signup for the event." Is it possible to retain the character case?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the wrong parameter from the filter. The following works like you would expect:

```
Route::filter('auth_message', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    if (!Auth::user())
    {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('errorAlert', $value);
    }
});

Route::get('/', function(){
    exit(Session::get('errorAlert')); // Returns "You must be logged into your account to signup for the event."
});
```

Comment: So how exactly would I use it with the Route::get()? I tried this:

`Route::get('event/signup', array('before' => 'auth_message', 'uses' => 'event@signup', 'message' => 'test'));`

However, it returns this error: `Missing argument 1 for Laravel\Bundle::{closure}()`

Comment: You don't need to change the event/signup route. Only change the filter to the code above. $value contains the value you passed on after the ":".

Comment: Okay, so I have this: `Route::get('event/signup', array('before' => 'auth_message:You must be logged into your account to signup for the event.', 'uses' => 'event@signup'));` but it's still throwing an error: `Missing argument 2 for Laravel\Bundle::{closure}()`

Comment: Okay, I got it to semi-work. The only thing I'm not completely satisfied with is that when the message is passed, it is converted to lowercase letters. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I've tested it and the message is not converted to lowercase. Try http://paste.laravel.com/n7e and visit /event/ you will get redirect to / and the error should display.

Comment: Interesting, just tried your exact code and I get this error still: `Missing argument 2 for Laravel\Bundle::{closure}()`